# MySQL - experience of employee in the days

Tags: mysql, database

I'm learning database query attempting to write a query that finds the user's total days experience for till today

Table "*emp_detail*":

| emp_no | join_date | exp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-12-01 | 840 |
| 2 | 2017-07-25 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-06-08 | 450 |

I'm able to get an exp. after joining XYZ. organization

I have tried using one of the threads while surfing:

```
SELECT
emp_no, 
join_date,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, join_date, CURDATE()) + (experience)  AS "total_exp",
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, join_date, CURDATE()) AS new_org_exp
FROM emp_detail
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oXqS3tq48QrqoBmYq8pEuR/4)

**Output:**

| emp_no | join_date | total_exp | new_exp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-12-01 | 2967 | 2127 |
| 2 | 2017-07-25 | 1010 | 1010 |
| 3 | 2022-06-08 | 562 | 112 |

Looking for another way to get total exp. employees if any

total experience 2967 days = (840 days [old experience with ABC. industry ] + 2127 [new exp. with new XYZ org. from onwards 01-12-2016])

Am I going in the right direction? Any help would be great.

Comment: The query seems to match what you are describing that you want.  So it is fine.  You may need some indexes on it going forward.  And probably the easiest way to get a grand total is to either run a separate query or just sum it in your back end language (if the number of rows in the result is not large).